# How to use $broadcast with components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular1.6

I have an angular 1.x app that uses components, and I would like to be able to broadcast messages in all my components. The context is the following : I have a service that gets websocket messages and I want to broadcast them to all my component controllers.

I thought of $broadcast but from what I have found [here](http://brandonclapp.com/using-angularjs-services-to-broadcast-messages-between-controllers/), it needs $scope and $rootScope. Which is incompatible with the use of component since I don't have $scope anymore in my app.

Is there a clean way to do that when using angular components?

Comment: your understanding of how angular works, and thus this question, are *slightly flawed*.  When using components and/or Controller As, **you are still using `$scope`, even if you aren't expressly referencing it.**.  It is perfectly acceptable to reference `$scope` in order to access `$broadcast`, without breaking the component pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using $braudcast for such a scenario.

Instead, create simple service that allows your components to subscribe to messages using Observables. You can create these Observables using either Rxjs or roll your own using the GoF subject/observer pattern.

This service would update the observables the WebSocket gets a specific message.

Even better, take a look at the Rxjs WebSocket implimentation.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Broadcast service is probably the cleanest way. Unless the components are in separate angular app modules. Here's a basic simple implementation:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, BroadcastService) {
  this.broadcast = BroadcastService;
});
app.component("listenerComponent", {
  template: "<h2>Listener Component</h2><section>{{ $ctrl.message }}</section>",
  controller: function($scope, BroadcastService) {
    $scope.broadcast = BroadcastService;
    this.message = $scope.broadcast.message;
    $scope.$watch('broadcast.message', function(newVal) {
      this.message = newVal;
    }.bind(this))
  }
});

app.component("broadcastComponent", {
  template: '<h2>Broadcast Component</h2><form ng-submit="$ctrl.broadcast()"><input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.newMessage"><button>Broadcast</button></section>',
  controller: function($scope, AppService) {
    this.newMessage = '';
    this.broadcast = function() {
      AppService.post(this.newMessage);
      this.newMessage = '';
    }
  }
});

app.factory("BroadcastService", function() {

  return {
    message: 'Default Message',
    post: function(message) {
      this.message = message;
    }
  }

})

app.factory("AppService", function(BroadcastService) {
  return {
    post: function(message) {
      BroadcastService.post("AppService Post Successful!!!" + message);
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Broadcast App</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <h1>Broadcast Message:</h1> {{vm.broadcast.message }}

    
    <listener-component></listener-component>
    <broadcast-component></broadcast-component>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment by Claies, it is perfectly possible to just use $scope while retaining the component pattern.
You can inject the components' controller with it and $broadcast, $emit, $on as usual.

```
// parentController
controller: function ($scope) {
    $scope.$broadcast('someevent', someargs);
}

// childController
controller: function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('someevent', function (event, args) {
        // function implementation...
    });
```